# Using Callable in Spring controller with WebApplicationInitializer getting IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following exception when I am trying to use Callable in my controller.

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.*

I am using java config & extend WebApplicationInitializer instead of using web.xml and added DelegatingFilterProxy but I am still getting the exception.

FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable async support for both your `Filter`

```
security.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

and your `Servlet`.